# No Root DSE returned from OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to set up an OpenLDAP server on ubuntu 9.10, which uses slapd version 2.4.18.

After initializing and populating a new hdb database, everything seems OK, but I can not get the server to return a root DSE. Running

```
ldapsearch -x -W -D 'cn=manager,dc=example,dc=org' \
    -b '' -s base '(objectclass=*)' +
```

just returns

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: +
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1
```

My hdb database ACLs are set up as follows:

```
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by anonymous auth
  by dn.base="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=org" write
  by * none
olcAccess: to dn.base=""
  by * read
olcAccess: to *
  by self write
  by dn.base="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=org" write
  by * read
```

From my experience this setup should have returned a valid root DSE, so if anyone could give me a clue as to what is going on...

Comment: On my config ldapsearch fail to retrive rootDN but my `LDAP Admin` can retrieve them before I enter any password/credential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually filed as bug [#427842](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openldap/+bug/427842) agains Ubuntu 9.10 (karmic).

To fix this, copy the following to fixRootDSE.ldif:

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: to dn.base="cn=subschema" by * read
```

And execute

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f fixRootDSE.ldif
```

This should give anonymous access to the root DSE.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't the Root DSE supposed to be queried anonymously, before binding as a user? So you shouldn't be using -W or -D at all.

My OpenLDAP server responds to the following:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base
```

with

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

#
dn:
objectClass: top
objectClass: OpenLDAProotDSE

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Comment: You're right, if the ldap server is configured right, you don't need to bind a user. But I get the same result both when I query anonymously and bind a user. And I don't get a unauthenticated response. So somehow the server don't answer any details about itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `namingContexts` using ldapsearch using optional attributes (`+` flag)

You need

- `-s base`
- `-b base`
- optional attributes `+` flag

In total,

```
    $ ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base +
```

As mentionned in this post https://superuser.com/questions/740877/how-do-i-query-the-available-base-dns-in-an-openldap-server

Answer (score 0):

For those who will get this error in Apache Directory Studio.

If you can see root DSE content in other browsers or ldapsearch, try create new connection. It helped me. I think it is a bug in Apache DS.

Comment: For others passing by, and having Apache DS or PHPLdapAdmin bug where Root DSE has no children, this is more likely to be a server problem (especially since LDAPAdmin does not have encounter it)

Answer (score 0):

For those who will get this error in Apache Directory Studio. also a restart on the studio helped.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to solve this, make sure your `slapd.conf` contains the ACLs to allow access to the rootDSE as without any configuration there is also no access:

```
# Sample access control policy:
#   Root DSE: allow anyone to read it
#   Subschema (sub)entry DSE: allow anyone to read it
#   Other DSEs:
#       Allow self write access
#       Allow authenticated users read access
#       Allow anonymous users to authenticate
#   Directives needed to implement policy:

access to dn.base="" by * read
access to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
```

The rootDSE **should** be accessible without authentication.