# Configure Jenkins with LDAP : parameter 'Root DN'

Tags: ldap, jenkins, slapd

I am installing an LDAP server and configuring Jenkins in order to accept LDAP for authentication. In Jenkins parameters, I have a weird behavior with the parameter `Root DN`.

[Documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin) says :

> **Root DN**
>
> For authenticating user and determing the roles given to this user, Jenkins performs multiple LDAP queries.
>
> [...]
>
> But in practice, LDAP servers maintain an extensive index over the data, **so specifying this field is rarely necessary** — you should just let Jenkins figure this out by talking to LDAP.
>
> If you do specify this value, the field normally looks something like dc=acme,dc=org

**Weird behavior** : If I do not specify the parameter, my user is not found. The others parameters have the default value.

LDAP is new to me so I am probably doing something wrong. I created a LDAP tree using `slapd`. I created one user `adenoyelle` under a node `People` that I also created. see `ldapsearch` result below :

```
root@myserver:~# ldapsearch -xLLL -b 'dc=acme,dc=com'
dn: dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: acme.com
dc: acme

dn: cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator

dn: ou=people,dc=acme,dc=com
cn: people
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
ou: people

dn: uid=adenoyelle,ou=people,dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: account
objectClass: top
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
uid: adenoyelle
```

If I let `Root DN` blank, my user cannot authenticate. But it works if I give this value for the parameter :

> ou=people,dc=acme,dc=com

What am I doing wrong? My guess is that my LDAP nodes are wrong but I cannot find why. Maybe a problem with `objectClass` values?

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP client will query the server for a root DSE used as base DN if you omit this value. If slapd isn't set up correctly, ldapsearch fails to get a value for that and thus fails the query.

Details here: [No Root DSE returned from OpenLDAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/81684/no-root-dse-returned-from-openldap), quoting:

> This is actually filed as bug [#427842](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openldap/+bug/427842) agains Ubuntu 9.10
>   (karmic).
>
> To fix this, copy the following to fixRootDSE.ldif:
>
> ```
> dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
> changetype: modify
> add: olcAccess
> olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
> olcAccess: to dn.base="cn=subschema" by * read
> ```
>
> And execute
>
> ```
> sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f fixRootDSE.ldif
> ```
>
> This should give anonymous access to the root DSE.